# Improve resolution for resizing gif(animated) images using Drawing2D in c#

Tags: c#, drawing2d

My image resizer will resize all images perfectly but gif(animated) images are somewhat grainy.

Currently I am using the `InterpolatioMode` as `HighQualityBicubic`. Is there any other parameters which would increase the resolution or any ideas how to improve the resolution for animated images?

Comment: Could you describe the way you want to size a pixel? Should it be perfectly square, or do you want to do a vector conversion first and then scale?

Comment: Hello sir, I am doing a vector conversion first. Maintaining the aspect ratio.

Comment: GIFs tend to be grainy by design, they can only have 256 colors.  Making them bigger just makes it more visible.